# Force the auto import to use ".js" extension in TypeScript Visual Studio Code Editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

The auto-import completion feature sometimes adds the `.js` extension, but not all the time. However, without the extension in the TypeScript source, the `tsc` compiler won't add the extension to the emitted JavaScript file which can create run-time issues such as module not found error.

For details of the problem please refer to: [Appending .js extension on relative import statements during Typescript compilation (ES6 modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat).

The question is: is there any way to configure the automatic import completion feature to force to append the`.js` extension in the import statements? Or are there any add-ons or VS Code extensions that can achieve this?

This minor thing has been extremely annoying at times!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that now the VSCode has it in the Preferences or Settings `Ctrl + ,` under the entry:
`"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js",`.

Comment: Do you know what "auto" relies upon for this setting? What are the "project settings" it refers to?

Comment: @slhck I am not sure because auto never worked properly for me. And even setting to "js" didn't work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text version

Install package "LSP-typescript". Click Preferences -> Package Settings -> LSP -> Servers -> LSP-typescript. Add following json

```
{
  "initializationOptions": {
    "preferences": {
      "importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js"
    }
  }
}
```

Or use this in tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext", // <- Necessary to get imports with .js
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm having my external libraries not working as an error appears: `This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import(...) has no call signatures`

Comment: Seems like there might be a few problematic libraries with this configuration. I was able to solve them using your solution and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74709714/2349947