# Typescript import ESM default export

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I feel this is a question that should be answered but cannot find an answer.

I've switched my TS project to ESM. So my `package.json` now has `"type": "module"` and my `tsconfig.json`:

```
 "target": "es2020",
 "lib": ["es2020"],
 "module": "node16",
 "moduleResolution": "Node16",
 "esModuleInterop": true, // Eases ESM support
 "types": ["node"],
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
...
```

For the most part things work great but a few modules give me trouble. For example [aedes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aedes) and [mqemitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqemitter) and [wait](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait)

```
import wait from 'wait'

await wait(1000)
```

The code above "works" but VSCode red underlines the "wait" in 2nd line w the error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/wait/wait")' has no call signatures.
```

I have tried of course:

```
import * as wait from 'wait'
```

and

```
import { default as wait } from 'wait'
```

I have what I thought was the relevant ESM settings in my TS config.

I am on TS 4.8.3 and using the latest of all these troublesome packages.

Most of the posts I see just seem to talk about `esModuleInterop`, etc.

Adding `.default` such as `wait.default()` makes error go away but code won't run. Seemed to work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924989/typescript-this-expression-is-not-callable-type-getuserinforequestdata-ob) though.one

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Ok. The error was throwing me off a bit - I usually see VSCode telling me to install `@types/...` or declare which is what I did.

```
declare module wait
declare module aedes
declare module mqemitter
```

However I don't think this is the solution. I literally have to do this for 15-20 modules and some, like `ajv` which are fully done in TS should not need this as I would have to somehow modify their entire type definition - on a side note `ajv` because I call it with a contructor as `new Ajv()` yields a slightly diff error `his expression is not constructable.`. There are issues seemingly related but nothing super concrete as of yet.

Here' a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/cyberwombat/ts-esm-test/draft/kind-sea?file=%2Findex.ts&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9bh5ug20002lrhb6woealfc%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cl9bh6bqv000blrhb74jv6h3z%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9bh6b2o00523b6fhlt7a3mv%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D).

Comment: Do you need `esModuleInterop`? If you remove it the import of `mqemitter` (CommonJS module) should not require the `.default` property access any longer.

Comment: I have tried removing and setting to false - same w `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` which is related (I think one sets the other) and no change at all.

Comment: @morganney It turns out that the "default" code I had didn't run and taking it off works but shows error in VSCode. Adding "default" removes error but causes code to not run.

Comment: @cyberwombat. I'm having the exact same problems as you. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: It has something to do with the "moduleResolution" setting. It was set to "NodeNext" which is what it should be, but if I change that to "Node" things just start working again. Seems like a TypeScript bug.

Comment: @Jeff see my answer - let me know if that works. I have it all working now and not exactly sure that was the actual fix to original problem so let me know.

Comment: Ahh - yes I guess that would work.. Nice

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52086) on the TypeScript repo that seems similar

Answer (score 4):

For the troublesome modules such as wait and ajv in my case I imported them into a utils file then reexported with a TS type as follows:

```
import wait from 'wait'

export const pause = wait as unknown as typeof wait.default
```

Comment: ah, really cool! This worked. Thanks! Is there a way I don't have to change the name or should I always create new const?

Comment: Do you mean how can you use 'wait' instead of pause? 
`import pause from 'wait'; export const wait = pause as unknown as typeof pause.default`

Answer (score 0):

I am working through this exact problem now, and the thing worked for me was changing `"moduleResolution"` to `"Node"`.

This, of course, brought about a few more problems specific to my env and build process, but for my case it was the better path forward.

Comment: That's commonJS module resolution - node ESM so it's not fully ESM so to speak. Part of the issue is exactly that - older CJS modules don't always play nice with ESM module resolution hence my question on how to "patch" these outdated modules.