# nodeJS v19 drops support for --es-module-specifier-resolution=node which makes it harder to run transpiled TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Typescript is transpiled to JavaScript, so a module `routes.ts` is converted into `routes.js` in the directory that `tsc` puts it.  If another module imports names (e.g., "router") from a module, we leave off the suffix as in:

```
import { router } from './routes'
```

This worked fine until node stopped using `.js` as a default suffix.  Starting in node V16 (or maybe earlier ?), it was necessary to add the flag
`--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` in order to run the transpiled code with node.
In later nodeJS versions this option was downgraded by being silently converted into
`--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` which was then dropped altogether in NodeJS v19.

Now in NodeJS v19, one is supposed to use "custom loaders" instead.  Is it really that hard to run transpiled TypeScript code?  What is the recommended approach?

(SO: says that this question duplicates the relatd question [Appending .js extension on relative import statements during Typescript compilation (ES6 modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat), but this question has more information concerning different versions of nodeJS -- it is related, so people might want to check it out.)

Comment: Since the ESM spec requires file extensions with `import`, I presume nodejs is just moving in the direction of the spec.  This sounds like something the TypeScript compiler should fix.  I wonder if this is being discussed in the TypeScript world.  Have you looked through the TypeScript compile options to see if there's an option to fix this (providing an extension in the generated code)?  Or looked where TypeScript issues are discussed?

Comment: Are you using ES modules or not? If yes, then include the `.js` extension in your imports and update your TS config as necessary.

Comment: What is it with the Node.js Foundation pushing these insane changes into Node? They now expect everyone to add ".js" in every import to millions of files? Jesus Christ, Bun can't come soon enough.

Answer (score 20):

**UPDATE**: I've created a package for this purpose and published it to `npm`. Anyone who's willing to use it can visit [its page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extensionless) for more information.

You can still use a custom loader with Node.js v19. Save the following to a file named `loader.js` in the project directory and then run `node` with the flag `--experimental-loader ./loader.js` added.

```js
import {existsSync} from 'fs'
import {basename, dirname, extname, join} from 'path'
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url'

let extensions = ['mjs', 'js', 'json'], resolveDirs = false

let indexFiles = resolveDirs ? extensions.map(e => `index.${e}`) : []
let postfixes = extensions.map(e => `.${e}`).concat(indexFiles.map(p => `/${p}`))
let findPostfix = (specifier, context) => (specifier.endsWith('/') ? indexFiles : postfixes).find(p =>
  existsSync(specifier.startsWith('/') ? specifier + p : join(dirname(fileURLToPath(context.parentURL)), specifier + p))
)

let prefixes = ['/', './', '../']
export function resolve(specifier, context, nextResolve) {
  let postfix = prefixes.some(p => specifier.startsWith(p))
    && !extname(basename(specifier))
    && findPostfix(specifier, context) || ''

  return nextResolve(specifier + postfix)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your package barhum. Since i had some problems supporting some es module features (like imports: {} in package.json) forked your work and create this alternative package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/specifier-resolution-node Would you give it a try ? ^^

Comment: @Poyoman Try with the latest version. It should handle both import aliases and deep imports from packages without file extensions.