# Compiled TypeScript can't find an exported module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to resolve an error in my TypeScript project. When I compile my code with this config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

it compiles without any errors but when i try to run my `Server.js` in my dist folder I get this error:

```
> node  dist/server.js

node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:255
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Documents\Development\AthletePT\dist\config\db' imported from C:\Users\Documents\Development\AthletePT\dist\server.js
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:255:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:908:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1121:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///C:/Users/Documents/Development/AthletePT/dist/config/db'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I can ensure you that the `db.js` exists in my dist folder and is being correctly exported. It's worth noting that this error didn't occur in Node.js 18. Because when I run:

> node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node dist/server.js

in Node.js 18 it seems to work. I don't know why this is happening. I think maybe it has something to do with how TypeScript is compiling my code, or it could be because JS has a problem with `import` in ESNext. My type in my `package.json` is set to `module`.

I already tried different ES version and targets. I tried different commands but nothing seemed to work. I am not able to test if it works with require statements because it would mean reworking my whole code.

Comment: What happens if you include the `.js` file extension in your imports? I believe Node v19 dropped the specifier resolution flag.

Comment: It doesn´t seem to help. Could specify how i can include it? I just put it into my tsconfig in the include tag. `"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "dist/*.js"]`

Comment: No, I mean _in the actual imports_. You don't actually show any of your code, but in `server.ts` there's presumably something like `import ... from "./config/db";` - make that `import ... from "./config/db.js";` and see what happens. Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74660824/3001761.

Comment: It seems to solve the problem because he now moves to the next module that has no .js extension. I don´t know if it will work because it will take a while digging truth my code and add .js everywhere. But thanks for you quick answere anyways!

Comment: That at least confirms what the problem is, why it seems to occur only with Node 20, and you can research the various options for dealing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue @jonrsharpe suggested to add *.js to the import statemenst.

```
import ... from ../yourtsfile.js
```

for my case it worked and he finds the exported modules.
On why this is happening i do some more resarche but i read something about that node refuses extensionles imports, but on the other hand TypeScript refuses to add import extensions at compile time. [Why do I need to include ".js" extension in Typescript import for custom module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75807785/why-do-i-need-to-include-js-extension-in-typescript-import-for-custom-module?rq=2)