# Cannot find module (when importing TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript file called server.ts, I run `npx tsc` to transpile the JavaScript. To start it, I then run `node dist/server.js`. This works.

If I add a file `db/mongodb-client.ts` and add an import to `server.ts` like this:

```
import db from "./db/mongodb-client";
```

and build again (`npx tsc`) I get two JavaScript files (`dist/server.js` and `dist/db/mongodb-client.js`). When starting (`node dist/server.js`) I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'dist\db\mongodb-client' imported from dist\server.
```

If I change the import to:

```
import db from "./db/mongodb-client.js";
```

it works. But that looks strange to me, since the source file is TypeScript. Do I need to configure something to get this working? Or build/start differently? Or am I expecting something wrong?

Comment: That's just how ES module resolution works by default. Yes you're writing .ts files but (as your opening paragraph states) they're transpiled to .js - that's what's failing to resolve at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat