# How to make my node.js server run in production mode?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node server, written in typescript, which is working fine using the debugger and vs code.

```
....
import { logIn, getLogins, findUser } from "./src/logins";
const app = express ();
app.use(express.json());
....
....
```

but when I try running `node dist\app.js` I get

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

so, [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/), I added  `"type": "module",`  to `package.json`. But now I am getting the error

```
[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ridehub-server\dist\src\logins' imported from C:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ridehub-server\dist\app.js
```

Please help! package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ridehub-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "learning",
  "main": "dist\\app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.ts",
    "dev": "tsx ..."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "quilkin\\ridehub-server"
  },
  "author": "quilkin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "linq": "^4.0.2",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.7",
    "xml2js": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.15",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.20",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.8",
    "tsx": "^3.14.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

and  tsconfig.json:

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2020",                               
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  },
  "references": [
    { 
        "path": "../ridehub-common",
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Value for `main` in `package json` will be `<output-dir>/app.js`  i.e the file that is produced after transpilation.

Comment: @chankruze OK, thanks, I have corrected that (post is now updated) but still have same error.

Comment: Your import is missing a file extension (`.js`/`.ts`).

Comment: @quilkin let me create a project with your settings and check the issue. If you can please provide a repo with these configs.

Comment: chankruze, thank you for the offer - creating a mini project has led me to the solution. And @cherryDT was (sort of) correct - I will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/)

The problem is in naming the file extensions for the imports:

```
import { logIn} from "./src/logins";
```

is what I had before. Adding the `.ts` extension (the logical one, sice that's the name of the file I am importing) gives the error

```
An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.ts(5097)
```

What is actually required is to add a `.js` extension instead.

```
import { logIn} from "./src/logins.js";
```

This seems totally illogical to me - there isn't such a file in that folder, it's only created in the `dist` folder after `tsc' is run.

Oh, and you cannot use `@/logins.js`, you have to use `./src/logins.js` or whatever.

Comment: I didn't know you were not familiar with this change in typescript. If you want old behaviour you can use a older version.