# Error when trying to import local modules in express server using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, export

I keep going arround in circles and every time I fix one issue, it breaks another. Below are the revenant scripts that keep giving me issues. The main problem is that the export and import of local files seem not to work. I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:40
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\[FULL PATH]\project\database' imported from C:\Users\[FULL PATH]\project\server.js
Did you mean to import ../database.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:233:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  url: 'file:///C:/Users/[FULL PATH]/project/database',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I've also tryed using `module.exports = db2` and for import I've tryed `import * as db2 from './database'` and `const db2 = require('./database')`. These all end up with their own errors.

PLEASE NOTE: This is NOT an issue with the mysql. I've tested the import with other local moduals and I have the same issue. This is also not an issue with async/await.

`Node.js v20.9.0`

server.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

/* EXPRESS */
const app = express()

/* DOTENV */
dotenv.config()

/* MYSQL */
//////////// THIS WORKS ////////////
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise'
const db1 = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
})
console.log({db1: await db1.query('SELECT * FROM table')})

//////////// THIS DOES NOT WORK ////////////
import db2 from './database'
console.log({db2: db2.query('SELECT * FROM table')}) // BREAKS ON THIS LINE

/* ROUTES */
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, world!")
})

/* START SERVER */
const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

database.ts

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise'

const db2 = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
})

export default db2
```

package.json

```json
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p . -w",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem has been addressed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat And the current best solution is to add the `.js` to your imports.

Comment: WOW! That is so stupid. 4 hours of troubleshooting because of 3 characters that you normally don't need? I can't believe that was the problem.

Comment: @SharpDev Do you know of a way to make it point to the `.js` by default?

Comment: As far as I know there is no super clean way of doing that (like a configuration or anything), and based upon the original github regarding this matter there are no plans for that to be added... `tsc-alias` is currently the option people use... But I've never used it before and I know it can be hard to setup... It includes an extra step at compile time but that's it.