# Node 20 - ESM import without .js file name extension not working

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I have created a clean node project:

[image]

I am running the command:

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js
```

Inside index.js I am importing sayHello WITHOUT the .js file extension. This should work because I have experimental-specifier-resolution=node and also type:module in the package.json.

package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.10.0"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

sayHello.js is:

```
export function sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

index.js is:

```
import { sayHello } from "./sayHello";

sayHello()
console.log(process.version);
```

[image]

Also, the same configuration works OK when using Node 16. Any idea what's missing?

Comment: It was _experimental_, you can see it in Node v18 docs (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/esm.html#customizing-esm-specifier-resolution-algorithm) but not v20 - _"Do not rely on this flag. We plan to remove it..."_

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, So in Node 20 there is no way to use the "import" syntax without specifying the ".js" file extension?

Comment: File extensions, get used to them.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like manual renaming in a smart way would be a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626938/412992

And update.