# TS-generated index.js does not find module

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

My generated index.js does not find a file I created. All this is by the ts compiler (It does exists).

Error: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'ssos-api/dist/server/graphql' imported from /ssos-api/dist/index.js`

/dist/index.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import graphqlServer from './server/graphql';
dotenv.config();
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import db from './config/db';
db();
const server = graphqlServer();
startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4000 },
}).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`  Server ready t ${url}`);
});
```

[existing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMcEa.png)

First TS Config used (apollo server docs default):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Current TS config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

package.json

```
{  
   "type": "module",
}
```

I've tried a lot of ts configs, but none of them works.

Comment: Please show also the file where this error occurs. But the import `ssos-api/dist/server/graphql` seems wrong ...

Comment: I just edited the original question

Comment: Your `index.ts` file should import `'./server/graphql.js';` and not `....ts`  because the `.ts` file won't exist in the `dist` tree ... See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat

Comment: Sorry, the index.js was not updated. I just updated the question showing the current /dist/index.js content. I'm using default apollo-server config (described in the original question)

Comment: Please read the question I linked. If you have `type: module` (ie you are using ES6 modules) in your `package.json` your relative `import` statements (ie `./path/to/file`) have to include a fileextension (in your case `.js`). Ie use `import graphqlServer from './server/graphql.js';` in your `index.ts` file and compile again.